# Xamarin.Android.Support issue

Tags: xamarin

Warning NU1608  Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment 27.0.2.1 requires Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1) but version Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 was resolved.

All I did was to install Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. I didn't specify any particular version. I don't see anything with the name Support.Fragment.

Not sure what to do.

Comment: What exactly is the question? It seems like you need to manually install the correct version of the *Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat* nuget package.

Comment: Added a line that I omitted.

Comment: *Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment* is probably a transitive package that comes as a dependency of another package. It itself seems to depend on a specific version of *Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat*. Just navigate to the package manager, select that specific version and press Update to downgrade it. Afterwards, the warning should be gone.